# Wordpress Vertical menu With Post Count

Tags: wordpress

I have a vertical menu in my sidebar as below

```
<li><a href="/computers" title="Computers">Computers<span class="count">1000</span></a></li>
```

So ,can I create a vertical menu like this one? with post count floated on the right side?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$variable = wp_list_categories('title_li=&echo=0&show_count=1');
$variable = str_replace( '(', '<span style="float:right;margin-top:-18px;font-size:11px;">(', $variable);
echo $variable;
?>
```

I did with this code it worked fine !